# Inkscape Filters

Tags: inkscape

I am using Inkscape 0.91. I wanted to use Filters -> ABC's Noise Transparency effect but it is not present in this higher version of Inkscape. I read online that in higher versions, "Noise Transparency" effect can be achieved by using "Noise fill" Filter but it does not provide the required result.
So, what should be used for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still use Inkscape 0.48, so the filter is available.

In my /usr/share/inkscape/filters folder there is a page named «filters.svg».

Inside it I found these lines:

```
<filter id="f114" inkscape:label="Noise transparency" inkscape:menu="ABCs" inkscape:menu-tooltip="Basic noise transparency texture" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="5" baseFrequency="0.02" result="result1" />
<feComposite operator="in" in2="result1" result="result2" in="SourceGraphic" />
<feColorMatrix result="result3" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 -1 " in="result2" />
</filter>
```

Maybe you can try to paste them into your own «filter.svg» file, probably just changing the `id="f114"` if there are conflicts.

**Don't forget to make a backup copy of your file, before!**

Comment: Glad to know! In this way you can have all the filters available in the previous versions and removed from the current one.

Answer (score 0):

They are present - just reorganized.
See https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/264535